# Foursquare API Combining data

Tags: foursquare, location-based-service

1) I notice that Foursquare does not show all places, but other engines show places that are not yet in Foursquare, but I would like to use  Foursquare API, so is there a problem showing a merged view of places from more than one engine providing attributions to both?

2) Even if I don't use both engines, but only foursquare and I create my own places (no other engine but my own), can I show a merged view of both of them?

If the above is not possible, what are my options of a location database that allows the above?

Comment: Did you come to any conclusions about this?

Comment: Currently I am moving towards using GooglePlaces to get me list of locations and will merge it with the places that I have. The Google Places license does not seem to indicate a "no usage" like Foursquare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the "Other Data" section of Foursquare's [Venues Database Usage Rules](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues#rules). Also from the FAQ: "Every venue should come from Foursquare. You are not allowed to maintain your own repository of venues alongside those from Foursquare—you should be using us as your sole location database. If a venue is not on Foursquare, you should add it."